# Time varying cointegrating equation

Tags: time-series, cointegration, kalman-filter, time-varying-covariate, vector-error-correction-model

I am estimating a rolling cointegration model and saving the parameters of the long run equation for trend analysis. I wonder if it is possible to estimate time varying parameter VECM using Kalman Filter on cointegrating equation instead of ecm or short run parameters.
Many thanks
mrrox

Comment: Is your question whether or not it is possible to cast the model in state space form and then let the long-run relations vector (often called the $\beta$ vector) vary according to a random walk process?

Comment: Hello @ Plissken, yes, can I do that? if Yes, do you know of a code on the net or someone who could help with get such a specification estimated?

Comment: I'll write an answer up later on what you can do. Letting the long-run relations vector vary according to a random walk process is problematic but if you are willing to use a Bayesian framework it should be possible. See: http://personal.strath.ac.uk/gary.koop/kls8.pdf. Note that Koop also publishes his Matlab replication files on his website.

Comment: Many thanks, it appears Koop published this paper with another guy in 2011. The code is in Gauss. Do you know if there is a matlab code of this sort? Thanks.